# Why can't typescript use string literals directly to compose an object type?

Tags: typescript

I have a literal type that I want to use to compose an object's type, and this literal type is used as a key for the object, but the following writing does not work correctly.

```js
type k = "name";
type v = string;

type obj = {
    [k]: v
}
```

Why does the above get an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use literals as keys you should use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
type obj = {
  [K in k]: v;
};
```

Result:

```
type obj = {
    name: string;
}
```

Comment: TIL about mapping a string prop. How does that excactly work? Does TypeScript treat `k` as a string union of single value?

Comment: @Behemoth you can interpret the mapped type as a looping. `k` is treated as a union and if you add another value to `k` like `"name" | "surname"`, `K` will be separately `"name"` and `"surname"`